# How to put an error message when putting the credentials wrong in a login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch

I am doing a login, and I need that when I enter the wrong password or the email I get an error message but I do not know how to do it, I am working with the POST method and also in nextjs

this is my code:

```
function Login({}) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("user-info")) {
    }
  }, []);
  async function login() {
    console.warn(email, password);
    let item = { email, password };
    let result = await fetch(
      "https://login-test.repl.co/auth/login",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(item),
      }
    );
    result = await result.json();
    localStorage.setItem("user-info", JSON.stringify(result));
  }
  return (
    <div className="bg-white w-full rounded-lg shadow p-2 h-screen flex justify-center items-center relative">
      <div className="w-full ">
        <input
          id="inputEmail"
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          type="email"
        />
        <input
          id="inputPassword"
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          type="password"
        />
        <button type="submit" onClick={login}>
          Login
        </button>
        <div className={`${!error ? "hidden" : ""}`}>
          INCORRECT PASSWORD OR EMAIL
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Login;
```

when I put the wrong password or the mail they send me this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check like this

```
function Login({}) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("user-info")) {
    }
  }, []);
  async function login() {
   setError(false);
    console.warn(email, password);
    let item = { email, password };
    try {
        let result = await fetch(
          "https://login-test.repl.co/auth/login",
          {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(item),
          }
        );
        result = await result.json();
        localStorage.setItem("user-info", JSON.stringify(result));

    } catch(error) {
        setError(true);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="bg-white w-full rounded-lg shadow p-2 h-screen flex justify-center items-center relative">
      <div className="w-full ">
        <input
          id="inputEmail"
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          type="email"
        />
        <input
          id="inputPassword"
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          type="password"
        />
        <button type="submit" onClick={login}>
          Login
        </button>
        <div className={`${!error ? "hidden" : ""}`}>
          INCORRECT PASSWORD OR EMAIL
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: Friend, it worked for me, but when I pass the api to you, what has to be, it doesn't work for me, I don't know if I can pass the api to you?

Comment: in async / await when an api call trigger and if that api return an error status (like 401, 422, 404 etc) and also want to catch that error then should wrap that api call with try-catch. if that api return other than 2xx response it will execute in catch section. like wise i changed the above code.  In catch you can check result.status to check response status. there you can write appropriate error handling. i can't understand what you mean by the above comment

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by checking the status code.

If you are getting status of 200 then you can update the state as follows:

```
if(result.status === 200)
{
    setEmail("Email Already Exists");
}
```

You can get more status codes and you can set the errors as you like.